# How to know if a Unicode identifier is valid?

Tags: python, unicode, python-3.x

Here is a sample scenario -

```
>>> এক = 1
>>> ১ = 1
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    ১ = 1
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier
```

I'm running this from default `python3` interpreter. Why do the first unicode string work as an identifier and not the second one?

Comment: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3131

Comment: ১ is a digit. Identifiers can't start with digits.

Comment: @LennartRegebro Duh! :| This was a silly question to start with. :|

Comment: Well, the reason you asked it was silly, but the question in itself is good. :-)

Comment: @LennartRegebro :) another question, how did you figure out that ১ is a digit? Just looking at it or some other method?

Comment: @Bibhas use str.isdigit(). ('এক').isdigit() return False and ('১').isdigit() return True

Comment: @Bibhas I searched for in in gnome.character-map. :-)

Comment: @LennartRegebro nice. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Valid identifiers are explained in the Python 3 documentation: [Lexical analysis - Identifiers and keywords](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers).

The exact details can found in [PEP 3131](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3131/).